# trying to pass pointer address to another pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to pass the address of one pointer to another pointer using the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int a = 45;
  int *int_ptr = &a;
  char *char_ptr;
  *char_ptr = *int_ptr;

  printf("char: %c", *char_ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

I compile the code and when I try to run the the program, I get this error: `34432 segmentation fault`

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: `char ch;char *char_ptr=&ch;`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings! "How can I fix that?" You do not take any address, but the value to an unspecified address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> *char_ptr = *int_ptr;
> ```

Here you don't copy the pointer but you copy the content to which `int_ptr` is pointing to the area where `char_ptr` is pointing. Since `char* char_ptr` is not initialized, you get the segmentation fault.

What you probably meant to write is

```
char_ptr = (char *)int_ptr;
```

instead of

```
*char_ptr = *int_ptr;
```

Comment: @Olaf accessing integer value by char pointer is OK. Visa versa would be a problem.

Comment: You are right about the aliasing (Sorry, I use `void *` as universal pointer, so I sometimes forget about the legacy special meaning of `char *`).

Answer (score 1):

To pass an address contained in a pointer, to another pointer you should use regular variable assignment;

```
char_ptr = int_ptr;
```

What you do is; you are trying to assign the value of `a` (`*int_ptr`) to variable pointed by `char_ptr` which is not pointed anywhere!

Note that you may have do type casting to get rid of some warnings;

```
char_ptr = (char*) int_ptr;
```

Comment: That's actually what I wanted to mean. Thanks for warning. Made some clarification.